# How to implement Spring Cloud Gateway with java fluent api or application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

`enter code here`i want to add SCG to my demo app but when i use the java fluent api method (@Bean in the config file) or set it in application.properties i get these errors:

** NOTE: i have another microservice running on port 8080

1- Java Fluent API

in my config file :

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r.path("/serv1/**"))
                    .uri("http://localhost:8080/"))
            .build();
}
```

i get this error:

> Parameter 0 of method gatewayRoutes in
> com.jbs.DemoCrudApi.Configuration.AppConfig required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder'
> that could not be found.

2- setting routes in application.properties

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=srv1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:8083
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/srv1/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RewritePath=/service1/(?<remaining>.*), /$\{remaining}
```

when i reach the end point i get 404(not found) error

what to do?

Comment: Show your dependencies in pom or Gradle file

Comment: dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.8</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: Not in comments, add it to the question

Comment: Gateway needs spring-cloud-starter-webflux, not -web. There should have been a warning or error on the logs